# Export Tensorflow graphs from Python for use in C++

Tags: python, c++, export, tensorflow, deep-learning

Exactly how should python models be exported for use in c++?

I'm trying to do something similar to this tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html

I'm trying to import my own TF model in the c++ API in stead of the inception one. I adjusted input size and the paths, but strange errors keep popping up. I spent all day reading stack overflow and other forums but to no avail.

I've tried two methods for exporting the graph.

Method 1: metagraph.

```
...loading inputs, setting up the model, etc....

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())


for i in range(num_steps):  
  x_batch, y_batch = batch(50)  
  if i%10 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:x_batch, y_: y_batch, keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: x_batch, y_: y_batch, keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: features_test, y_: labels_test, keep_prob: 1.0}))

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
checkpoint = 
   '/home/sander/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/cat_face/data/model.ckpt'
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint)

   tf.train.export_meta_graph(filename=
   '/home/sander/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/cat_face/data/cat_graph.pb',  
    meta_info_def=None,
    graph_def=sess.graph_def,
    saver_def=saver.restore(sess, checkpoint),
    collection_list=None, as_text=False)
```

Method 1 yields the following error when trying to run the program:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR 
google/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:532] String field 
'tensorflow.NodeDef.op' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol 
buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes. 
E tensorflow/examples/cat_face/main.cc:281] Not found: Failed to load 
compute graph at 'tensorflow/examples/cat_face/data/cat_graph.pb'
```

I also tried another method of exporting the graph:

Method 2: write_graph:

```
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, 
'/home/sander/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/cat_face/data/', 
'cat_graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

This version actually seems to load something, but I get an error about variables not being initialized:

```
Running model failed: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized  
value weight1
[[Node: weight1/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@weight1"], 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](weight1)]]
```

Comment: There's "Method 3: use freeze_graph". That avoids having to use Variables and run restore ops -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py

Comment: Ah, I've seen that. But I struggle to find out how to fill in its arguments, just like I don't know what to fill out for every argument in export_meta_graph. Do you know of some example code for this?

Comment: There's an example here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph_test.py

Comment: Thanks a lot Yaroslav. I'll give it a try. Will the c++ procedure be equivalent to the one in the tutorial?

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html

Comment: Alright, it seems like the freeze_graph is really working.. Great!

I did encounter another error when running the graph in c++ however. It says that the input image is of the wrong type and should be a feed dict. What's a good way to resolve this? Should I change something in c++ or set up the graph differently in python? Are the placeholder variables a problem here? I'll show the error in the next comment.

Comment: Running model failed: Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
  [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used C++ or freeze_graph at all...maybe file a bug and see if Pete Warden wants to take it? (he wrote most of freeze_graph)

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Saving and Restoring a model in TensorFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/5000/saving-and-restoring-a-model-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Looks like you're saving it in binary format, whilst trying to read as text.

Answer (score 3):

At first, you need to graph definition to file by using following command

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
//Build network here 
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), "C:\\output\\", "mymodel.pb")
```

Then, save your model by using saver

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables()) 
saver.save(sess, "C:\\output\\mymodel.ckpt")
```

Then, you will have 2 files at your output, mymodel.ckpt, mymodel.pb

Download freeze_graph.py from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) and run following command in C:\output\. Change output node name if it is different for you.

> python freeze_graph.py --input_graph mymodel.pb --input_checkpoint mymodel.ckpt --output_node_names softmax/Reshape_1 --output_graph mymodelforc.pb

You can use mymodelforc.pb directly from C.

You can use following C code to load the proto file

```
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/image_ops.h"

Session* session;
NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);

GraphDef graph_def;
ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), "C:\\output\\mymodelforc.pb", &graph_def);

session->Create(graph_def);
```

Now you can use session for inference.

You can apply inference parameter as following:

```
// Same dimension and type as input of your network
tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({ 1, height, width, channel }));
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> finalOutput;

// Fill input tensor with your input data

std::string InputName = "input"; // Your input placeholder's name
std::string OutputName = "softmax/Reshape_1"; // Your output placeholder's name

session->Run({ { InputName, input_tensor } }, { OutputName }, {}, &finalOutput);

// finalOutput will contain the inference output that you search for
```

Comment: what tensorflow version Deniz?  The reason I ask is that the `saver.save` function In the package I'm using seems to create a `.ckpt.meta` file. I'm assuming that's the same thing that `saver.export_meta_graph` creates...Recent internet research seems to indicate that this was a difference between R11 and R12, but you wrote this so recently that I'm wondering which version you used.

Comment: I verified this code with currently up-to-date tensorflow source. However, ckpt.meta files are not needed for C++ run as you already export by using "write_graph". I will update the code to prevent confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (modify name of output layer):

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util


def load_graph_def(model_path, sess=None):
    sess = sess if sess is not None else tf.get_default_session()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path + '.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, model_path)


def freeze_graph(sess, output_layer_name, output_graph):
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    # Exporting the graph
    print("Exporting graph...")
    output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess,
        input_graph_def,
        output_layer_name.split(","))

    with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())


def freeze_from_checkpoint(checkpoint_file, output_layer_name):

    model_folder = os.path.basename(checkpoint_file)
    output_graph = os.path.join(model_folder, checkpoint_file + '.pb')

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        load_graph_def(checkpoint_file)

        freeze_graph(sess, output_layer_name, output_graph)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_from_checkpoint(
        checkpoint_file='/home/sander/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/cat_face/data/model.ckpt',
        output_layer_name='???')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find very useful the [DNN](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html) module of OpenCV.
It makes it simple to load and use pretrained models developed with Tensorflow (and other frameworks).

It can be used in a C++ program.

[Here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/08/21/deep-learning-with-opencv/) is a tutorial.