# Define a feed_dict in c++ for Tensorflow models

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, deep-learning

This question is related to this one:
[Export Tensorflow graphs from Python for use in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682832/export-tensorflow-graphs-from-python-for-use-in-c)

I'm trying to export a Tensorflow model from Python to C++. The problem is, my neural net starts with a placeholder to receive input, which requires a feed_dict. I cannot find any c++ API to supply a feed_dict for my model. What can I do?

If there's no API for supplying feed_dicts, how should I change my model so that it can be trained and exported for c++ purposes without placeholders?

Comment: Just a guess, but I would think the android image recognition app does something like this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`tensorflow::Session::Run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/cc/ClassSession.html#virtual_Status_tensorflow_Session_Run) method is the C++ equivalent of the Python [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) method, and it supports feeding tensors using the `inputs` argument. Like so many things in C++ versus Python, it's just a little more tricky to use (and in this case it looks like the documentation is a bit poorer...).

The `inputs` argument has type `const std::vector<std::pair<string, Tensor>>&`. Let's break this down:

- Each element of `inputs` corresponds to a single tensor (such as a placeholder) that you want to feed in the `Run()` call. An element has type `std::pair<string, Tensor>`.
- The first element of the `std::pair<string, Tensor>` is the *name* of the tensor in the graph that you want to feed. For example, let's say in Python you had:

  ```
  p = tf.placeholder(..., name="placeholder")
  # ...
  sess.run(..., feed_dict={p: ...})
  ```

  ...then in C++ the first element of the pair would be the value of `p.name`, which in this case would be `"placeholder:0"`
- The second element of the `std::pair<string, Tensor>` is the value that you want to feed, as a [`tensorflow::Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/cc/ClassTensor.html#class-tensorflow-tensor) object. You have to build this yourself in C++, and it's a bit more complicated that defining a Numpy array or a Python object, but here's an example of how to specify a 2 x 2 matrix:

  ```
  using tensorflow::Tensor;
  using tensorflow::TensorShape;

  Tensor t(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({2, 2}));
  auto t_matrix = t.matrix<float>();
  t_matrix(0, 0) = 1.0;
  t_matrix(0, 1) = 0.0;
  t_matrix(1, 0) = 0.0;
  t_matrix(1, 1) = 1.0;
  ```

  ...and you can then pass `t` as the second element of the pair.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I can work with this and I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: Hey MrRy, it worked! I'm very happy with the result. 

I'd also like express my appreciation for the fact that google engineers, who no doubt have busy schedules, find the time to help relative new comers like me to get Tensorflow working! It took me about 2 weeks and 6 stackoverflow questions to build a conv net and export it to c++, but you guys really helped me out a lot!