# What is the syntax to be used for feed_dict in TensorFlow C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I want to build and train a graph in TensorFlow **C++** that consists of two layers, and to feed it with a given matrix as an input.

I have two different examples for the syntax:

[The official C++ example (line # 129)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc)

[An old answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36817586/6456078)

It seems they contradict each other with respect to the exact syntax of the "input" parameter to tensorflow::Session::Run()

Should it be "placeholder_name:0" or "placeholder_name"?

Answer (score 1):

Either one works. The name gets passed through [ParseTensorName](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/graph/tensor_id.cc#L28), where names without a colon are assumed to have an output index of 0. To verify this, we can add a ":0" to the end of the feed name in [DirectSessionMinusAXTest::TestFeed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session_test.cc#L124):

```
std::vector<std::pair<string, Tensor>> inputs = {{x_, t}};
```

becomes

```
std::vector<std::pair<string, Tensor>> inputs = {{x_ + ":0", t}};
```

and it still passes.

The only case where passing an output index is required (more accurately the only case where it should be required; there may be some code lacking canonicalization) is if you're feeding a Tensor which is not the zeroth output of an operation (e.g. "unique:1"). This is quite rare, since constant and placeholder ops are the most likely feed targets and only have a single output.