# Using graph_metrics.py with a saved graph

Tags: tensorflow

I want to view statistics of my model by saving my graph to a file then running [graph_metrics.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/graph_metrics.py).

I have tried a few different things to write the file, my best effort is:

```
tf.train.write_graph( session.graph_def, ".", "my_graph", as_text=True )
```

But here's what happens:

```
$ python ./util/graph_metrics.py --noinput_binary --graph my_graph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./util/graph_metrics.py", line 137, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File ".virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./util/graph_metrics.py", line 85, in main
    FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "./util/graph_metrics.py", line 109, in calculate_graph_metrics
    input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_layer)
  File ".virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2531, in get_tensor_by_name
    return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)
  File ".virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2385, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File ".virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2427, in _as_graph_element_locked
    "graph." % (repr(name), repr(op_name)))
KeyError: "The name 'Mul:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'Mul', does not exist in the graph."
```

Is there a complete working example of saving a graph, then analyzing it with `graph_metrics.py`?

This process seems to involve a magic incantation that I haven't yet discovered.

Comment: Related question where I got my basic approach to saving: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36682832/86967

Answer (score 1):

The error you're hitting is because you need to specify the name of your own input node with `--input_layer=` (it just defaults to Mul:0 because that's what we use in one of our Inception models):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/graph_metrics.py#L51

The graph_metrics script is still very much a work in progress unfortunately, and you may hit problems with shape inference, but hopefully this should get you past the initial hurdle.

Comment: Thanks.  This was a good hint, and did move me forward.  Still not there though -- too many moving parts for me to guess the rest.  At this point, I do have  `calculate_graph_metrics()` working when I use it as a function call from within my app -- it just doesn't work if I try to use a graph file.